# How to get the current query DB_HOST value in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.5, master-slave

In this location:  ..\config\database.php

```
   'mysql' => [
                'read' => [
                    'host' => env('DB_HOST_READ', '127.0.0.2'),
                ],
                'write' => [
                    'host' => env('DB_HOST_WRITE', '127.0.0.1'),
                ],
                'driver' => 'mysql',
//                'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
                'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
                'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                'prefix' => '',
                'strict' => false,
                'engine' => null,
            ],
```

.env file added:

```
DB_HOST_READ=127.0.0.2
DB_HOST_WRITE=127.0.0.1
```

Look the read and write host values. I want to verify the host used for the current running query for both read and write queries.

I am using Laravel 5.5 . So how can I get DB_HOST value for each query?

Comment: DB::connection()

Comment: do I have to echo it ? and will it show for the current query ? Do I have to echo it before or after running the query (query can be read type or write type)

Answer (score 0):

```
env('DB_HOST_READ');
env('DB_HOST_WRITE');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the config helper function.

```
$readHost = config('database.mysql.read.host');
$writehost = config('database.mysql.write.host');
```

This will take into consideration the value on the env file, any default value you might specified in the database.php config file (env('VALUE_FROM_ENF',"default value")).

reference: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration